# Date formatter is returning un identified date

Tags: ios, swift

I've a function that returns the formats the date into a specific format. As one of my customer raised an issue, we found that his device date is submitting in wrong format, i.e, "09/08/0001 16:50:38" which should be something like this 09/08/2019 16:50:38

Here is my code

```
func getDateAndTimeStringFromDate(serverDate : Date?) -> NSString?{
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
            let dateStr : String = dateFormatter.string(from: serverDate!)
            if Validations.isNullString(dateStr as NSString) == false{
                return dateStr as NSString
            }
            return nil
    }

 let currentTime = Date()
let strDate = getDateAndTimeStringFromDate(serverDate: currentTime)
```

This issue is occurring only iPhone 7 plus with 12.4.1.
Please note that I'm getting date in "09/08/0001" format only.
Can anyone help me out of this.

Comment: Specify the fixed `en_US_POSIX` locale. And why `NSString`? This is Swift. And why is the parameter `serverDate` optional? Let the compiler tell you at **compile time** if you are going to pass `nil`

Comment: Try specifying locale and timezone for dateFormatter.

Comment: Thanks for your response, let me check and get back to you @JayrajVala

Comment: Yes, If doesnt work, i will be happy help you @MahendraThotakura

Comment: But @JayrajVala, I don't understand why special characters are added in date (09\/08\/0001) ?

Comment: It can not happen. May be you are doing something wrong. Your code looks clear. Meantime let me write code in answer.

Comment: Could you please try the following if it fixes your issue: `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy' 'HH':'mm':'ss"`

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste this code and see if it works.

```
let _deviceFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    df.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    return df
}()

func localDateString(from date: Date?) -> String {
        if let _ = date{
            return _deviceFormatter.string(from: date!)
        }else{
            return ""
        }
    }
```

Comment: Let me know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: Sure @jayajVala will let you know